# sharepoint document vs windows document same size

Tags: 2010

is a 10kb document on a hard drive same size when it is uploaded in share point or is there some kind of compression ratio .. .
I want to move 5 gig documents from my windows folder to share point, will it occupy 5 gig on my sqlserver . if SP has a special way of storing it is there a formula that i can use to determine the hard drive size of my sqlserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a formula I came across not too long about about how to estimate the size of a content database from the size of your files:

http://njbblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-40-formula-for-estimating.html